# CSS3: Orbiting rings in 3D space (with example)

Tags: css, animation

I think I may have hit something above my pay grade with this but.. I'm trying to get 3 rings to circle around in 3D space (*similar to electrons around the nucleus of an atom*).

[Here's a few codes I've tried.](http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/elqan)

It seems like I can rotate, I can skew, but I can't do both at the same time without a complex matrix equation (and I'm lost on those for now).

Here's an example I made to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish in CSS

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for this ? (3d)

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/aKCuv

animations are delayed and each value of transform are declared.

Comment: Not exactly, updated OP. *btw, there's no animation in Firefox*

Comment: it does in mine , i used prefixed free in codepen option (FF22)

Comment: for the difference of transform you used, you should use rotatey() rotatex() and rotatez() with skewy() skewx(). the ball will be a problem. (please , excuse my average and naive english :) ).

Comment: Very nice solution! I didn't see rotate(x,y,z) in the code though (or any Z axis). Can't wait to play with it tomorrow - still learning CSS animation, this should be a big help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wrappers. The HTML:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<img src="http://s23.postimg.org/3zqc7rp6j/orbit_ring.png" class="rotate" />
<div class="reversed"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/3zqc7rp6j/orbit_ring.png" class="rotate reversed" /></div>
<div class="skew-1"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/3zqc7rp6j/orbit_ring.png" class="rotate" /></div>
```

and the CSS

```
.skew-1 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateX(10px) translateY(10px) skewX(10deg) skewY(10deg);  
}
.skew-2 {
  transform: scale(1) translateX(-10px) translateY(-10px) skewX(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);  
}
.rotate {
   position:absolute;   
  -moz-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;  
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0    { -moz-transform: rotate(0); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.reversed {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1.2, -1.1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";    
}
```

**Codepen:** http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/bEnfK

I have seen the new video in the question. Edited some properties to make it look like the video:

[new codepen](http://www.cdpn.io/IKqBA)

Comment: np, always good to have a demonstration, btw +1 for the solution.

Comment: looks a little buggy compared to mine , isn't ? NO need to use wrapper if all transform values are rewritten in animation !

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no need to use wrappers. And for my own work, I try to have the minimun HTML posible. However, I thought that the OP would understand it better this way. And, also yes, your answer  is really good.